# React Router Dom deletes vales when I change page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm creating a REACT App using  `react-router-dom` for the navigation, the links are working but if I'm (for example) filling a form and I change the page then If I come back the values are gone!

I used just a couple of times a while ago and if I remember well as long as you don't reload the page it saves the loaded values (forms or results of researches for example), but this doesn't?

Am I wrong?
Is it a problem with my configuration?

Comment: In react-router, the Route component simply checks the URL and if matched (URL starts with path), then it will render the passed component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's kind of expected in terms of how React Router works under the hood.  React Router will only mount components that match the criteria of the router and remove the other routes from the node tree as well as the DOM.

If you want to keep these values around, you need to keep their state around longer than the route.  One way to do that is to use the [`render`](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Route/render-func) form of the `Route` so that you can keep the stateful values directly adjacent to the router as apposed to keeping them in the child component of the route.  The other way of doing this is to use something like Redux to keep state external to the components and thus longer lived.

I have created an example below that demonstrates using the 3 different ways.  If you flip back and forth between Home and the Forms, the values will persist for 2 of them, but reset for the one without.

- `form-without-persistence` won't persist.  It uses a component whose state will get thrown away every mount cycle (changing routes).
- `form-with-render-persistence` keeps its state within the component that renders the `Router` so its state will continue to live even though we stop rendering it while not on its route.  This is OK for small data sets, but you'll have to keep **all** the data here which means a lot of `useState()` in the router, especially if you have multiple forms.
- `form-with-context-persistence` will persist its state because it uses a [`Context`] to store data which keeps the data out of the `Router` component but still retrievable.  The example `Context` is very rudimentary, but demonstrates the same concept that something like [Formik](https://formik.org/) or Redux would do.

```js
const {createContext, useState, useContext} = React;
const {render} = ReactDOM;
const {BrowserRouter: Router, Route, Link} = ReactRouterDOM;

const formContext = createContext([
    "",
    () => console.log("Would set name")
]);

const {Provider: FormProvider} = formContext;

const Form = ({children}) => {
    const nameState = useState("");
    return <FormProvider value={nameState} children={children} />;
};

const useFormContext = () => useContext(formContext);

const FormWithoutPersistence = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");

    return (
        <form onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("You tried to submit");
        }}>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Form Fields</legend>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span>Name</span>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={name}
                            onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};

const FormWithContextPersistence = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useFormContext();

    return (
        <form onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("You tried to submit");
        }}>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Form Fields</legend>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span>Name</span>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={name}
                            onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");

    return (
        <Router>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/form-without-persistence">Form without persistence</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/form-with-render-persistence">Form with render persistence</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/form-with-context-persistence">Form with context persistence</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                <div>
                    <p>I'm the home page!</p>
                </div>
            )} />
            <Route path="/form-without-persistence" component={FormWithoutPersistence} />
            <Route path="/form-with-render-persistence" render={() => (
                <form onSubmit={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log("You tried to submit");
                }}>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Form Fields</legend>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                <span>Name</span>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    value={name}
                                    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            )} />
            <Route path="/form-with-context-persistence" component={FormWithContextPersistence} />
        </Router>
    );
};

render(
    <Form><App /></Form>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.2.0/umd/react-router-dom.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Super clear! I always use `redux` but I thought the the persisting was made by the `router`. I just implemented `redux` in the app so I'll try to see the differences.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the values are resetting has nothing to do with `react-router-dom`. You didn't post your code here, but I can guess that each route of yours renders a different component.

That means that when you change route by pressing on a `<Link />`, the current component (the one that holds the form, for example) gets unmounted, and so all of its state is deleted. When you come back to this link, the component remounts, but it has already lost its data when it was unmounted.

If you want to keep your data between pages, I recommend using React's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), or a global store library such as [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start#:%7E:text=React%20Redux%20is%20the%20official,the%20store%20to%20update%20data.) or [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html)